# npx create-react-app my-app stuck after installing packages

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app, npx

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.20.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 7 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.1.2
├─ react-dom@17.0.2
├─ react-scripts@4.0.3
└─ react@17.0.2
info All dependencies
├─ cra-template@1.1.2
├─ immer@8.0.1
├─ react-dev-utils@11.0.4
├─ react-dom@17.0.2
├─ react-scripts@4.0.3
├─ react@17.0.2
└─ scheduler@0.20.2
Done in 368.65s.
```

create-react-app stuck after this. Even after I manually terminated the Job and executed the command "npm start" still not working.
any fixes for this problem ?

Comment: I tried most of the solutions provided on the net. At last, I installed node js for 32 bit, it worked for me. Thanks for your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option is to try using `npm` instead of yarn.

```sh
npx create-react-app my-app --use-npm
```